# GAE Upgrade Datastore not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, upgrade, google-cloud-datastore

I just upgrade GAE 1.7.4 to 1.7.5 and face below problem when access data store:

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage; local class incompatible
```

After I delete exiting `local_db.bin`, it works fine.

That is very troublesome as every time upgrading will need recreate new `local_db.bin` which means all my exiting data is gone. Is there any way to upgrade the data store to new version and reuse the exiting data?

This problem remain in latest 1.8 version and here the error stack track

```
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: High Replication
    Storage: D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
13/05/2013 12:18:17 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService load
INFO: Failed to load from the backing store, D:\Workspaces\GoogleAppEng\cea-AppEngine\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6214581437134474035, local class serialVersionUID = -5740281364528697394
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1583)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1029)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService.load(LocalDatastoreService.java:1552)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService.startInternal(LocalDatastoreService.java:554)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService.access$300(LocalDatastoreService.java:135)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$2.run(LocalDatastoreService.java:547)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService.start(LocalDatastoreService.java:544)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.startServices(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:599)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.access$700(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:46)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:584)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl$2.run(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:581)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.getService(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:580)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.DatastoreViewerServlet.init(DatastoreViewerServlet.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at temp.HttpIfModifiedSinceFix.doFilter(HttpIfModifiedSinceFix.java:53)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:438)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: you can probably write it all out and in again with the bulk loader tool.

Comment: This problem remain in latest 1.8 version and here the error stack track

Comment: TBH I'd not expect upgrades to "care" about existing data for the dev server. Ensuring backwards compatibility for the emulated datastore in the local dev server is probably low on the list of priorities.